# Kotlin enum via reflection

Tags: kotlin, reflection, enums

I wonder is there any better way to parse enum when you don't have Generic and have only  `KProperty1<T, *>`?

I have found / come up with solution like this:

```
enum Car {
    BMW, AUDI
}

val property = properties[fieldName] as? KProperty1<T, *>
val instanceKClass = property.returnType.jvmErasure

if (instanceKClass.java.isEnum) {
   parseEnum(property.javaField!!.type as Class<Enum<*>>, "BMW")
}


fun parseEnum(enumClass: Class<Enum<*>>, value: Any?): Enum<*>? {
    val enumClz = enumClass.enumConstants
    return try {
       enumClz.first { it.name == value }
    } catch (ignored: Exception) {
       throw IlligalArgumentException("there is no such enum")
    }
}
```

I'm trying to extract enum value from string in Kotlin via reflection and I want to find best possible way of doing this

P.S. I'm looking for advice how to do it more efficient and nice, because I'm not really satisfied with this way.

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? Anything you don't like about your current solution?

Comment: @Sweeper yeah, I don't like this iteration `enumClass.enumConstants.first()` and this cast `as Class<Enum<*>>`. I haven't mentioned but I have `if` check that this is an enum. There is some old ticket in JB traker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14743/Reflection-Access-enum-values-and-valueOf-via-KClass but I couldn't apply something like this, so this is why I decided to ask some advice

Answer (score 1):

This should work for what you are looking for. This extension function will work with any defined Enum, and enforces correct class safety. The function will return null on non expected values, and is reasonably tolerant to the string format.

```
enum class Car {
    BMW, AUDI, ASTON_MARTIN;
}

inline fun <reified T: Enum<*>> getEnum(value: String): T? {
    val entries = T::class.java.enumConstants
    val enumNameFormat = value.uppercase().replace(" ", "_")

    return entries.firstOrNull { it.name == enumNameFormat }
}


fun usage() {
    val car = getEnum<Car>("BMW")
    val caseInsensitive = getEnum<Car>("bmw")

    println("Car: $car caseInsensitive: $caseInsensitive")
    
    val underscoreName = getEnum<Car>("Aston_Martin")
    
    println("Aston: $underscoreName")
    
    val notCar = getEnum<Car>("John Deere")
    
    println("Not Car: $notCar")
}

usage()

/*
  Car: BMW caseInsensitive: BMW
  Aston: ASTON_MARTIN
  Not Car: null
*/
```